# How do to i insert var into url in load()?

Tags: jquery, url, load, var

I am trying to pull the specific part of a page using load()
like this

```
    var divid = y;
    $page.load("mypage.php?id=1 #"+divid+" ");
```

Above script works well. My question is that how do I change id of URL within `load()` function ? I tried following one but it doesn't work.I don't know where the syntax error is
        `var another-id-I-get = x;
        $page.load("mypage.php?id="+another-id-I-get+" #"+divid+" ");`
 I am generating another id as below 
         `id=$(this).attr('class');
     $page.load("mypage.php?id="+id+" #"+divid+" ");`

Comment: Your code should work.

Comment: are you sure another-id-I-get (or x) is valid, i.e. it is not null ?

Comment: I am pretty sure the id is valid because I can use  AJAX to pass the id to another php page
maybe is the way how I get the id  wrong?
I am doing like this<code>var anothervalue=$(this).parent().attr("class");</code>